# jQuery toggle animation only works when double clicking

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a problem when you press the red button the animation start and then if you click in blue button it doesn't work but in double click it works

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/2Mtgf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having the problem is because there is no shared state between the `open` and `close` buttons. So when you click on the `close` button and it closes the container, `open` still thinks the container is still open, requiring two clicks to produce the desired behaviour.

You could use the following code, although it doesn't use toggle (new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XzS8E/3/)):

```
<div class="main">
    <a class="open"></a>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="close"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="containerState" style="display:none;">opened</div>
</div>
```

```
$('.open').click(
    function () {
        if ($('#containerState').text() == 'opened')
            CloseContainer();
        else if ($('#containerState').text() == 'closed')
            OpenContainer();
    });

$('.close').click(
    function () {
        CloseContainer();
    });


function OpenContainer()
{
    $('.container').animate({
        right:"0px"
    }, 500);
    $('.open').animate({
        right:"300px"
    }, 500);

    $('#containerState').text('opened');
}

function CloseContainer()
{
    $('.container').animate({
        right:"-300px"
    }, 500);
    $('.open').animate({
        right:"0px"
    }, 500);

    $('#containerState').text('closed');
}
```

Comment: i know it but the blue button must be open and close the container... and red button only close the container

Comment: @AramMkrtchyan - I've modifed the code to preserve the state of the container between the two buttons.

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
<div class="main">
    <a class="open o"></a>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="close o"></a>
    </div>
</div>


 $('.open').click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('o')){

            $('.container').animate({
                right:"-300px"
            }, 500);
            $('.open').animate({
                right:"0px"
            }, 500);

     }else{

            $('.container').animate({
                right:"0px"
            }, 500);
            $('.open').animate({
                right:"300px"
            }, 500);           
        }
 $(this).toggleClass('o','c');  
 $('.close').toggleClass('o','c');   
});

  $('.close').click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('o')){

            $('.container').animate({
                right:"-300px"
            }, 500);
            $('.open').animate({
                right:"0px"
            }, 500);

     }else{

            $('.container').animate({
                right:"0px"
            }, 500);
            $('.open').animate({
                right:"300px"
            }, 500);           
        }
  $(this).toggleClass('o','c');  
 $('.open').toggleClass('o','c');    
});
```